# Npm module with different code with and without proxy support

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, transpiler

How can I create a javascript library (distributed as module on npm) with different implementations depending on whether the environment it gets run in (transpiled to??) has proxy support or not?

As I understand it babel doesn't (at least easily) support transpilling proxies so this isn't easily fixable just via transpilation.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

## 1: Use a Proxy polyfill

An example is [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill) (which I think should be good enough) or [this](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect).

## 2: Check whether the `Proxy` variable exists

Unless you declared a variable named `Proxy`, I think this should be good enough.

```js
console.log(typeof Proxy !== 'undefined')
```

This will output a `Boolean` value whether Proxy is available.

Example usage of the above:

```js
if(typeof Proxy !== 'undefined') {
  // run code that uses Proxies
  console.log('I can use Proxies here!')
}
else {
  // run code that doesn't use Proxies
  console.log('Oops! I can\'t use Proxies here!')
}
```

**NOTE: You have to use `typeof` to check whether the `Proxy` variable exists or not, as it will just return `undefined` instead of throwing an error.**